# preg_replace not working but regex working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove anything between simple quotes in a string from a file:

```
$file = file_get_contents("myfile");
preg_replace("/(')(.)*?\1/", "", $file);
```

The regex works on http://regexr.com/ but has no effect in php.
There are many occurrence in the file.

Is there something special about the quotes because they are from a file ?
What would be the process and why is mine not working ?

Comment: Hum, if it's duplicate I'll try to find it and remove my question.

Comment: Clarifying: use `preg_replace('/(\').*?\1/', '', $file);`. You may keep the question. Also, do not use  http://regexr.com/ to test PHP regex, use regex101.com or others that are PCRE regex compatible. Regex101.com also has a *code generator* section that generates the right code for you.

Comment: It's still not working. I'll read the post you linked me.

Comment: Not working how? Do you assign the result to the variable? `$file = preg_replace('/(\').*?\1/', '', $file);`

Comment: XD okay, this one was dumb. Thanks for the help, I'll now use single quotes and regex101.com.